# Browser crash on Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, chromium

I have a browser app that's consistently crashing at the same point, on an Android 4.4.4 emulator. I haven't figured out exactly what the app is trying to do at the point it crashes, but I'm wondering if someone can help diagnose it.

This is an app built with Sencha Touch 2.4.1. It crashes in the native browser. Incidentally, it also crashes when I run it from inside a Cordova app.

It's happening on an Android 4.4.4 emulator, Intel Atom (x86) processor, 1024x600 display, running on a Mac OS X 10.11.3 host, with the HAXM 6.0.1 extension. It didn't happen on Android 4.4.2 or 5.1.1 emulators.

The logcat output is below:

```
I/chromium( 1275): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
E/chromium( 1275): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_autogen.h(1082)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:583CB4B9]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GetIntegerv: <- error from previous GL command
...
F/libc    ( 1968): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 1968 (any.testandroid)
I/DEBUG   (  936): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  936): Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86/sdk_x86/generic_x86:4.4.4/KK/1743154:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  936): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (  936): pid: 1968, tid: 1968, name: any.testandroid  >>> com.mycompany.testandroid <<<
I/DEBUG   (  936): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  936): 
I/DEBUG   (  936): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  936):     #00  pc 002dc3f1  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkGpuDevice::SkGpuDevice(GrContext*, GrTexture*)+33)
I/DEBUG   (  936):     #01  pc 015c4e82  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so (cc::ApplyImageFilter(cc::GLRenderer*, cc::ContextProvider*, gfx::Point, SkImageFilter*, cc::ScopedResource*)+145)
I/DEBUG   (  936): 
I/DEBUG   (  936): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5ae0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5ae4  00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5ae8  b6f42119  /system/lib/libskia.so (GrResourceCache::find(GrResourceKey const&, unsigned int)+9)
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5aec  b709fbe4  /system/lib/libskia.so
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5af0  bf9f5b38  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5af4  b87a5bd0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5af8  bf9f5b20  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5afc  b6f09ead  /system/lib/libskia.so (GrContext::lockAndRefScratchTexture(GrTextureDesc const&, GrContext::ScratchTexMatch)+349)
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b00  b898d180  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b04  bf9f5b20  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b08  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b0c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b10  b76ff800  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b14  b88ca520  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b18  00000044  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b1c  00000072  
I/DEBUG   (  936):     #00  bf9f5b20  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b24  00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b28  00000072  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b2c  00000044  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b30  00000005  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b34  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b38  a8f16753  /dev/ashmem (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b3c  00440072  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b40  00000005  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b44  00000003  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b48  00000002  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b4c  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b50  b8990e60  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b54  b8b238b0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b58  b6f09d59  /system/lib/libskia.so (GrContext::lockAndRefScratchTexture(GrTextureDesc const&, GrContext::ScratchTexMatch)+9)
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5b5c  aed01e94  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  936):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  936):     #01  bf9f5ba0  bf9f5c98  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5ba4  b87a5bd0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5ba8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5bac  b87a5bd0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5bb0  bf9f5c00  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5bb4  b8990e60  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5bb8  bf9f5fc4  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5bbc  b8b238b0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5bc0  b8956000  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5bc4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5bc8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5bcc  b85d3b40  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5bd0  0000003d  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5bd4  00000022  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5bd8  00000072  
I/DEBUG   (  936):          bf9f5bdc  00000044  
D/Zygote  (  939): Process 1968 terminated by signal (11)
W/InputDispatcher( 1254): channel 'b42049d8 com.mycompany.testandroid/com.mycompany.testandroid.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher( 1254): channel 'b42049d8 com.mycompany.testandroid/com.mycompany.testandroid.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
E/JavaBinder( 1254): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
W/ActivityManager( 1254):   Force finishing activity com.mycompany.testandroid/.MainActivity
D/        ( 1254): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8666ab0, tid 2023
W/InputDispatcher( 1254): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'b42049d8 com.mycompany.testandroid/com.mycompany.testandroid.MainActivity (server)'
I/WindowState( 1254): WIN DEATH: Window{b42049d8 u0 com.mycompany.testandroid/com.mycompany.testandroid.MainActivity}
D/dalvikvm( 1254): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 518K, 16% free 6606K/7848K, paused 17ms, total 19ms
W/ActivityManager( 1254): Exception thrown during pause
W/ActivityManager( 1254): android.os.DeadObjectException
W/ActivityManager( 1254):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager( 1254):   at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:660)
W/ActivityManager( 1254):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:761)
W/ActivityManager( 1254):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2443)
W/ActivityManager( 1254):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2320)
W/ActivityManager( 1254):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2050)
W/ActivityManager( 1254):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9548)
W/ActivityManager( 1254):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9441)
W/ActivityManager( 1254):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:10086)
W/ActivityManager( 1254):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:9637)
W/ActivityManager( 1254):   at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
I/ActivityManager( 1254): Process com.mycompany.testandroid (pid 1968) has died.
```

Comment: on Cordova generally people don't post DEBUG dumps because they can't tell us much. Was you app ever working? Is so, what did you change?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650: Is there a way to get a more useful stack trace? Not sure if it was working on this device before.

Comment: I had two (2) questions. Are you ignoring them?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650: I'm not sure if it was working on this device before, so I can't tell you whether I changed anything that broke it.

Comment: Then you are wasting everyone's time. Always start with a "known good" or "known working" example.  Find a "hello world". If you can't get that to work, then more education is needed. Best I can do for you. Best of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and i came across by doing following thing..

1. Remove all your plugins by using the command `Cordova plugin rm url of the plugin`
2. Remove your platform by using `cordova platform rm android`
3. Add again platform and plugins.